# Computer won't return from sleep without pressing power button when lid is raised

Tags: windows-7, sleep, lid

My friend is having a problem. She is using the Windows 7 operating system, and when she closes the lid, the computer goes to sleep fine. The problem, however, is when the lid is opened, it won't return from sleep unless she presses the power button again. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I wish I had this same problem, but my wife keeps flipping my lid, and pushing my buttons till I wake up...

Answer (score 0):

There is an option under the power settings "What to do when lid closes", you can tell it not to power off I believe, more information can be found here: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-laptop) It is probably going into hibernation mode after a while.